# Query to find zip codes with ending '0000'

Tags: sql-server

I need to find all zip codes in the database that end with '0000'.  Using the below query, I was able to return all zip codes that are 9 digits in length.  But how do I add return back only those zipcodes that have are 9 digits in length AND have 0000?  I'm sure it's simple but I'm still really new to querying.  :)

example: 922340000

```
Select Addresszipcode
from dbo.CR_MEMBER_AllMemberDetails
where len(Addresszipcode) = 9
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select Addresszipcode
from dbo.CR_MEMBER_AllMemberDetails
where len(Addresszipcode) = 9
and Addresszipcode like '%0000'
```

Comment: @DanField Neither is yours. You have a function wrapping the column, so it will do a full table scan. Only way around a table scan it would be a calculated indexed column.

Comment: Right, I realize that.  I think yours is easier to fix to make it sargable.  Mine was just the first thing that came to mind for me.

Comment: Thank so much Dan!  I knew it was simple I was missing!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Addresszipcode 
FROM dbo.CR_MEMBER_AllMemberDetails 
WHERE LEN(AddressZipCode)= 9 AND RIGHT(AddressZipCode, 4) = '0000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the [LEN() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) and the [LIKE operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

```
SELECT Addresszipcode FROM dbo.CR_MEMBER_AllMemberDetails
WHERE LEN(AddressZipCode)=9 AND AddressZipCode LIKE '%0000'
```

The `LEN(AddressZipCode)` part of the `WHERE` clause will only return rows with a length of `9`. The `AddressZipCode LIKE '%0000'` will only return rows that end with `0000`. When using the `LIKE` operator, the percent sign `%` acts as a wildcard. In essence, you're saying "WHERE AddressZipCode starts with anything and ends with 0000".

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, here is the SQL to trim the 0's:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(AddressZipCode)=9 AND AddressZipCode LIKE '%0000' 
            THEN LEFT(AddressZipCode,5) ELSE AddressZipCode END AS AddressZipCode
```

Comment: @Michelle - If you need a more detailed explanation of how this works, let me know.